# Get selected value(s) RadComboBox client side

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

I have rad Combo box

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="rcb" Height="150px" OnItemsRequested="rcb_ItemsRequested" AutoCompleteSeparator="," >
 </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

I need to get Selected value from client side 
i tried this

```
function getvalue()
{
    var combobox = $find("<%= rcb.ClientID %>");
    var value = combobox.get_selectedItem().get_value();
}
```

but get_selected Item get only last selected item .
I need to get all selected Item.

Comment: When is the getvalue() method called?

Answer (score 0):

try the get_text() method http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-client-side-radcombobox.html to get the entire input

here is a basic sample that seems to do the trick

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="rcb" Height="150px" OnItemsRequested="rcb_ItemsRequested" AutoCompleteSeparator=",">
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="text" OnClientClick="getSel(); return false;" runat="server" />
            <script>
                function getSel() {
                    alert($find("rcb").get_text());
                }
            </script>
```

and

```
protected void rcb_ItemsRequested(object sender, RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        rcb.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(i.ToString()));
    }
}
```